# ArgumentNull exception Entity Framework7

Tags: entity-framework

Please I'm using this code to get entities from the sql server database

MyDbContext dbct = new MyDbContext ();
IQueryable query = dbct.MyEntity;

But eache time I try to fetch my query I get those exceptions

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: constructor
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ConstructorInfo constructor, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.CreateMaterializeExpression(IEntityType entityType, Expression valueBufferExpression, Int32[] indexMap)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.MaterializerFactory.CreateMaterializer(IEntityType entityType, SelectExpression selectExpression, Func`3 projectionAdder, IQuerySource querySource)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalEntityQueryableExpressionVisitor.VisitEntityQueryable(Type elementType)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.EntityQueryableExpressionVisitor.VisitConstant(ConstantExpression constantExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.ReplaceClauseReferences(Expression expression, IQuerySource querySource, Boolean inProjection)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CompileMainFromClauseExpression(MainFromClause mainFromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.CompileMainFromClauseExpression(MainFromClause mainFromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitMainFromClause(MainFromClause fromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.MainFromClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.SqlServerQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<CompileQuery>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: There's really not much information in your question, but at a glance it looks like your entity type doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: thank you very much I forgot to add a parameterless constructor

Answer (score 1):

This really is an exception that Entity Framework should catch and wrap into a user-friendly exception, but what it's trying to tell you is this:

The entity type does not have a parameterless constructor defined.

Add it, and the exception will go away.